# Is it possible to count conditionally on this mysql table

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the weak title, I was having trouble wording it.

I'll explain my problem here, it is much easier to understand if I can show you what I am looking for help with.

I have a table that tracks the number of calls my system makes. Each call can have any number of attempts.

I have a very simple table

```
 | attemptId(pk) | callId | isFailed |
 |      1        |    1   |     0    |
 |      2        |    1   |     1    |
 |      1        |    2   |     0    |
```

I have been counting the number of distinct calls by simply using this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT callId) FROM mytable WHERE isFailed = '0';
```

On the table above, it returns a count of 1. The result I am looking for is 0. If a call fails on any attempt I would want to ignore it in my distinct count.

On the surface, I feel like the query to return a count of 0 on this table should be simple, but I cannot think of it(I am not good with mysql).

Is that query possible?

Comment: the needed results where not totally clear because of the low number of records, see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)  .. what should happen if you have more 0 records?

Comment: Unless i miss something very very very obvious thing about your question, i believe you can use -> . 

    `SELECT
     CASE 
      WHEN unique_c = 1
      THEN 0
      ELSE unique_c
     END
    FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT callId) As unique_c FROM mytable WHERE isFailed = '0';
    ) AS alias`

Comment: I've added another row. I tried your query and it gives me a count of 2, instead of 1 (which would be expected in the table above)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can eliminate failed `callId`s with `not exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select count(distinct callId)
from mytable t
where not exists (
    select 1
    from mytable t1
    where t1.callId = t.callId
    and t1.isFailed = 1
)
```

Comment: This is pretty interesting. I think you in-inadvertently solved another issue I have had for a long time as well. 

This query is immensely faster than the other query I was using. Would you happen to have an idea why?

Comment: @RWri: my query has just one level of aggregation, whereas the other query has two levels. I guess that's what makes the performance difference.

Comment: Ok makes sense, I'll do some more research on it. Thanks again, this was unexpectedly awesome.

Answer (score 1):

You can use two levels of aggregation:

```
select count(*)
from (select callid
      from t
      group by callid
      having min(isfailed) > 0
     ) c;
```

The subquery returns calls that have no `isfailed = 0`.  This assumes that `isfailed` takes on 0 or positive values.  The more general expression would be:

```
having sum(isfailed = 0) = 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! This works perfectly, but the answer from GMB is much faster.

Comment: I am not sure if there might be some confusion. I don't mean he was faster to respond, but that the actual execution time is faster. 58s vs 9mins.

Comment: @RWri . . . I fully understood.  Better performance is a very good reason to choose an answer.  I even upvoted that answer.

Comment: Ok perfect, my misunderstanding! I appreciate the time you took to answer, thanks again. Have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

You could use:

```
SELECT callId, COUNT(DISTINCT callId) * MIN(isFailed)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY callId
```

The count will be multiplied by 0, if there is any failed attempt, by 1 otherwise :)

Note that, it will give you just 1, as you are counting distinct `callId`.

I suggest using `COUNT` without `DISTINCT`.

Comment: *"Note that, it will give you just 1, as you are counting distinct callId.

I suggest using COUNT without DISTINCT."* i would only suggest removing `DISTINCT` if the table structure is clear that `callId` to be unique per callId group as the table structure and data within can alter the meaning (results better said) of a SQL query..